# JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. JAXB object does not have a successflag xml property

Tags: web-services, soap, jaxb

I am exposing a web service whhich accepts data and inserts this data to DB and returns a successFlag if insertion is complete. I am not using any interface. The web parameters are given directly in the implementation class itself. When testing, the data is being inserted. But the SOAP response received shows JAXBWrapperException.

PFB the implementation java code, the WSDL,soap response and stack trace.Please tell me what is wrong.

### Java impl class

@WebService
public class Service11_SAPCall {

```
Connection connect = null;
ResultSet result = null;

public void GetSrnDetails(
        @WebParam(name = "clear_db", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) String clear_db,
        @WebParam(name = "count", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) int count,
        @WebParam(name = "srnList", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) srnDetailsBean[] srnList,
        @WebParam(name = "status", mode = WebParam.Mode.IN) String status,
        @WebParam(name = "successflag", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<String> successFlag,
        @WebParam(name = "failedSrnList", mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<ArrayList<String>> failedSrnList) 
{
    boolean dataFlag = false; //to identify if data is being inserted
    ArrayList<String> failed_srn_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Logger LOGGER = null;
    try 
    {
        Handler fh = new FileHandler("/data/build/Service11.log");
        LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Service10_SAPCall.class.getName());
        Logger.getLogger("LOGGER").addHandler(fh);
        LOGGER.info("Logger Name : "+LOGGER.getName());
        System.out.println("GetSrnDetails execution begins");
        System.out.println("Inside GetSrnDetails");
        LOGGER.info("Inside GetSrnDetails");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        fin = new FileInputStream("/data/build/ENivesh/Properties/DB_connection.txt");
        props.load(fin);
        //DB connection details
        String connection_url=props.getProperty("DCURL");
        String uname=props.getProperty("DCUserId");
        String pwd=props.getProperty("DCPwd");
        fin.close();

        //Load Driver
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver Loaded");
        System.out.println("connection_url="+connection_url+"\nuname="+uname+"\npwd="+pwd);

        System.out.println("Inside getcount");

        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(connection_url,uname,pwd); 
        connect.setAutoCommit(false);
        Statement stmt_insertCount = connect.createStatement();
        int insert_count_status = 0;
        int insert_data_status[] = null;

        //Inserting the received count and status to DB
        String insert_count = "insert into SRN_COUNT_SERVICE11(DSD_SRN_STATUS,SRN_COUNT) values ('"+status+"','"+count+"')";
        insert_count_status=stmt_insertCount.executeUpdate(insert_count);

        //Inserting data passed if any.Data is passed only for beyond time line statuses.
        if(status.equalsIgnoreCase("HIAB-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("WIPG-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PTPR-BT") 
            || status.equalsIgnoreCase("UPDH-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PPRE-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PDMD-BT") 
            || status.equalsIgnoreCase("UPAO-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PQAO-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PQRO-BT") 
            || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PAID-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("PQDH-BT") || status.equalsIgnoreCase("UPDH-BT"))
        {
            if(srnList.length != 0)
            {
                Statement stmt_insertData = connect.createStatement();
                String insert_data = null;
                for(int i=0; i<srnList.length; i++)
                {
                    insert_data = "insert into SRN_DTLS_SERVICE11 values "
                            + "('"+srnList[i].getSrn()+"','"+srnList[i].getStatus()+"','"
                            +srnList[i].getUserId()+"','"+srnList[i].getMobileNumber()+"','"
                            +srnList[i].getCompanyEmailId()+"','"+srnList[i].getAddressType()+"','"+srnList[i].getAddress()+"','"
                            +srnList[i].getCityCode()+"','"+srnList[i].getStateCode()+"','"+srnList[i].getDistrictCode()+"','"+srnList[i].getCountry()+"','"
                            +srnList[i].getCompanyname()+"','"+srnList[i].getTelNo()+"','"+srnList[i].getRocCode()+"','"+srnList[i].getDate()+"')";
                    stmt_insertData.addBatch(insert_data); 
                }
                insert_data_status = stmt_insertData.executeBatch();
                for(int j=0; j<insert_data_status.length; j++)
                {
                    if(!(insert_data_status[j]>0))
                        failed_srn_list.add(srnList[j].getSrn());
                }
                dataFlag = true; //setting to true as data was inserted
            }
        }
        connect.commit();
        if(insert_count_status > 0) {
            if(dataFlag) {  //If data is inserted, failed_srn_list is checked to see if any insertions failed.If no X is passed.
                if (failed_srn_list.size() == 0)    {               
                    successFlag.value = "X";
                }
                else {
                    failedSrnList.value.addAll(failed_srn_list); //if there are failed insertions, the failed SRNs are passed back to SAP.
                }
            } //If dataFlag is not set, only insertion of count is considered to set successFlag.
            else {
                successFlag.value = "X";
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.severe(ex.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            connect.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            LOGGER.severe(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

}

WSDL

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sap="http://sapservice.me.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sap:GetSrnDetails>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <clear_db></clear_db>
         <count></count>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <srnList>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <srn></srn>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <status></status>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <date></date>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <userId></userId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mobileNumber></mobileNumber>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <companyEmailId></companyEmailId>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <addressType>Home</addressType>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <address>home</address>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <cityCode>cuty</cityCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <stateCode>state</stateCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <districtCode></districtCode>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <country></country>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <telNo></telNo>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <companyname></companyname>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <rocCode></rocCode>
         </srnList>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <status></status>
      </sap:GetSrnDetails>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### SOAP error

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. The org.me.sapservice.jaxws.GetSrnDetailsResponse JAXB object does not have a successflag xml property.</faultstring>
         <detail/>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Stack Trace

```
000000b9 AxisEngine    E org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine receive org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. The org.me.sapservice.jaxws.GetSrnDetailsResponse JAXB object does not have a successflag xml property.
                                 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. The org.me.sapservice.jaxws.GetSrnDetailsResponse JAXB object does not have a successflag xml property.
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:242)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:208)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:172)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.WASAxis2Servlet.doPost(WASAxis2Servlet.java:1583)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1227)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:458)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1032)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3761)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:976)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. The org.me.sapservice.jaxws.GetSrnDetailsResponse JAXB object does not have a successflag xml property.
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.marshalResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:511)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.createResponse(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:349)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.dispatcher.JavaBeanDispatcher.invoke(JavaBeanDispatcher.java:141)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.EndpointController.invoke(EndpointController.java:111)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.server.JAXWSMessageReceiver.receive(JAXWSMessageReceiver.java:161)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. The org.me.sapservice.jaxws.GetSrnDetailsResponse JAXB object does not have a successflag xml property.
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperToolImpl.wrap(JAXBWrapperToolImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.marshalResponse(DocLitWrappedMethodMarshaller.java:482)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading the WAS FP **8.5.5.10** to **8.5.5.12**. We had two Services with exactly same method name but different *targetNameSpace*,like DomainService1 has **'get'** method and DomainService2 also has **'get'** method, but WAS 8.5.5.12 throws this exception and doesn't give any clue to find the root cause. Apparently WAS is more strict in recent version with the naming of the methods.

**This was the exception:** *org.apache.axis2.jaxws.wrapper.impl.JAXBWrapperException: An internal assertion error occurred. The com.xxx.web.myapp.services.jaxws.GetResponse JAXB object does not have a xxxxxStatus xml*

After changing the name of the method specific to each service 'getABC' and 'getPQR' it worked!!!

hope this works!